# Restrict docker containers to listen to local subnet access only

Tags: firewall, docker-networking

I saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053824/how-to-restrict-that-a-docker-container-only-listens-connection-from-localhost:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 your_image_name
```

But I want to restrict access to the local subnet such as `127.0.0.*`. Do I have to setup a iptables filter for this.

PS There are containers with specific ports that still need to access the outer internet:

```
  mycontainer:
    image: myimage:latest
    container_name: mycontainer
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
      - WEBUI_PORT=8080
    volumes:
      - <>:/config
      - <>:/downloads
    ports:
      - 8080:8080         # < need to restrict to local subnet
      - 50016:50016
      - 50016:50016/udp   # <---- still needs outside access!
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Listening on the loopback interface already restricts access to 127.0.0.0/24. What more do you want?

Comment: I have these docker services running on the host (which is behind a NAT) and has the IP 192.168.206.35. I have setup wireguard VPN with this server as host and connect from my client box (VPN node: 10.13.13.2) to access these services... As it stands anyone within the physical subnet can access these services. I want to restrict access to my VPN client only. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I just saw that you referred to the whole subnet.... thanks!

Comment: I have an issue with setting up that VPN... I have a follow-up question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1143381/setting-up-tunneling-for-docker-containers